What is the contextual interpretation of Psalm 141:3?
We read in Psalm 141:3-4 (NIV):

3.Set a guard, O Lord, over my mouth;  keep watch over the door of my lips!
4. Do not let my heart incline to any evil,
to busy myself with wicked deeds
in company with men who work iniquity,
and let me not eat of their delicacies!

Read in isolation, the Psalmist is praying in Verse 3 that the words which fall out of his mouth be monitored. But in Verse 4, he hints at the possibility of having forbidden food in the company of evil men and wants to steer clear of such a wicked deed.
My question is: What is the interpretation of Verse 3 of Psalm 141 when read with Verse 4?

As a supplementary point to all 3 good answers already given, re. not eating the delicacies of evildoers:  the Psalmist set out in the opening Psalm the way contact with evil people degenerates. It starts with walking alongside them, it then turns into standing with them, and ends up sitting with them. Sitting would be part of eating with them; being given delicacies indicating favour or even favouritism.

Psalm 141:3-4 may make more sense together with 141:5;

3 Set a guard over my mouth, Lord; keep watch over the door of my lips.
4 Do not let my heart be drawn to what is evil
so that I take part in wicked deeds
along with those who are evildoers;
do not let me eat their delicacies.
5 Let a righteous man strike me—that is a kindness;
let him rebuke me—that is oil on my head.
My head will not refuse it,
for my prayer will still be against the deeds of evildoers. (NIV)

David faced many adversities in his life: being pursued by Saul, betrayed by his son Absalom, and punished by God for his sin with Bathsheba. In all these situations, he did not retaliate with his own strength. He refrained from killing Saul when he had the chance, fled from Jerusalem despite having mighty warriors with him, and did not kill Shimei for cursing him. David accepted everything that happened to him as God's will and did not act against it.
His prayer was to keep his heart from being drawn to evil. Jesus said in Matthew 15:11-18;

11 "What goes into someone’s mouth does not defile them, but what comes out of their mouth, that is what defiles them....... 18 But the things that come out of a person’s mouth come from the heart, and these defile them. (NIV)

Therefore Psalm 141:3&4 are parallel, emphasizing the need to guard both the heart and the mouth. The word "delicacies" in verse 4 represents seduction. David is saying he will confront his adversaries, and would rather be struck by the righteous than accept the benefits from the wicked.

Psalm 141:3-4 ESV

3 Set a guard, O Lord, over my mouth;
keep watch over the door of my lips! 4 Do not let my heart incline to any evil,
to busy myself with wicked deeds in company with men who work iniquity,
and let me not eat of their delicacies!

The point: David wants God’s help in maintaining righteousness and avoiding sin. Together we see the importance of both words and actions.
Words
Verse 3: "Set a guard, O Lord, over my mouth; keep watch over the door of my lips!”
It seems clear that David is asking God to help him control his speech.

Death and life are in the power of the tongue,
and those who love it will eat its fruits. (Proverbs 18:21)

He does not want to say anything that brings death. Anything sinful.
Actions
Verse 4: “Do not let my heart incline to any evil,
to busy myself with wicked deeds
in company with men who work iniquity,
and let me not eat of their delicacies!”
Tell me what Company you keep and I will tell you what you are. 1
Those who commit iniquity can lead others to participating in their sinful actions. I other words, “eating of their delicacies.”
David does not want to fall into sin through either what he says or what he does.

1 - Moral Instructions of a Father To His Son Upon His Departure for a Long Voyage

There is nothing wrong and per se evil in delicacies, for as the Lord says, nothing that enters man defiles him (Mark 7:18-20), but only when those delicacies are shared with wicked men! Why? - because delicacies are served as a desert, by the end of a meal, which means that one has fully appreciated and even enjoyed the company of crooks and scoundrels for a couple of hours, delighting in their filthy jokes and boastful narrations of naughty feats. Moreover, since he is offered the delicacies by those wretches, that means that the liking is mutual and reciprocal, and we can be 99% sure that neither he remained silent during the meal, but shared with them some slanderous gossips to please and placate their ears.
Otherwise, why not eat the same delicacies if offered by good and upright people? No reason whatsoever!

Thanks, Levan. Having control on your speech is one thing ;  having control on your tastebuds is another. Leviticus 11 which gives a definitive list of 'unclean food ' does not however, spell out the punishment ( other than the defaulter becoming unclean till evening) to be given to one who consumed forbidden food. Jews scrupulously observed the law in regard to clean and unclean food . David being the King had pretty good  chances of breaking the rules of purity. Hence his humble prayer. My doubt is whether Verse 3 is a precursor to that prayer.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan I guess, I mismatched your question: you asked from a historical-ethnographic Old Testamental perspective and I answered from the New Testamental commonsensical perspective.

That is right, Levan. Mk.7 does not annual ex-post -facto the Leviticus 11  rules .  I hope the early Xtians continued refraining  from pork . There was perhaps a concern for ecological balance in those rules in that they forbade eating insect- eating birds and scavengers. Pigs for example were the cleaners of the city dustbin. Similarly, Jews were encouraged to primary and secondary sources of energy . The Leviticus rules were more of social than of individual nature in so far as the observants were concerned.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan I agree, that there is a lot of ethnography in Old Testament, that is why the Lord explodes all that by His words that "nothing that enters defiles man" in Mark; of course, the early Christians of Jewish origin did not immediately abstain from pork and other ritualistically precluded animals, but there was already a divine/metaphysical notion/"Begriff" that all that was just an ethnography. Newly convert Greek Christians, I guess, did not change their diet and Roman centurions just turned Christians ate crispy fried piglets with honey - a Roman recipe - all the same.

PS: Please read " annul" in place of " annual" in my Comment above.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan You need ‘t have written, I guessed it :)
